# GLSL ES local variables crash?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to implement some shaders from online tutorials (lighthouse3d.com) in my OpenGL ES 2.0 engine.

The problem is that for some reason, ANY variables declared in the scope of main() causes the entire shader to fail. for example, this fails:

```
void main(){
    vec4 color;     
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
}
```

but this works perfectly:

```
void main(){
    //vec4 color;       
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
}
```

Same thing happens with my vertex shaders.(**EDIT**:nvm, only seems to happen with fragment shaders) The only way to use any type of non-constant value is to use attributes, varyings, uniforms, etc. for example, this works as you would expect:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying lowp vec4 fragcol;
varying lowp vec2 texco;

void main(){
    gl_FragColor = fragcol * texture2D(texture, texco);
}
```

Also, I'm having a hell of a lot of trouble trying to find documentation or resources specifically about GLSL ES (or whatever this version is called). All I've been able to find is this: http://old.siggraph.org/publications/2006cn/course16/KhronosSpecs/ESLanguageSpec1.10.11.pdf

This is all I could find related to variable declarations:

> [snip]There are no default types.  All variable and function declarations
>   must have a declared type, and optionally qualifiers. A variable is
>   declared by specifying its type followed by one or more names
>   separated by commas.[snip]

And that is exactly what I did:

declared type: **vec4**

followed by one or more names: **color**;

```
vec4 color
```

I'm clueless

**EDIT:**
GLES20.glGetError() gives error 1282

Comment: What compiler/implementation are you using?

Comment: oops! I knew I forgot something. I'm developing on Android using the android development kit.. I should update my post

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GLSL ES differs from traditional GLSL in that it requires precision modifiers in order to specify a full type. Have you tried, e.g.:

```
void main(){
    lowp vec4 color;     
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
}
```

You can also throw something like this into the top of a source file:

```
precision highp float;
```

To set the default precision, so you can omit it later on.

To get detailed information about an error compiling GLSL, you can use `glGetProgramInfoLog` (with assistance from `glGetProgramiv`). Most GL implementations return a meaningful error and a line number. I'm sadly backward with Java, but in C you might do:

```
    glCompileShader(shader);

    // check whether compilation was successful; if not
    // then dump the log to the console
    GLint status;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if(!status)
    {
        GLint logLength;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
        if (logLength > 0)
        {
            GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, logLength, &logLength, log);
            printf("Shader compile log:\n%s", log);
            free(log);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "[Shader Error] Link Error: Fragment shader was not successfully compiled." >_> not very useful   **EDIT:** Logs were a failure so I tried adding the precision modifier and it worked! I think that bit information should have been easier to find. Thanks for the help

Comment: @AlexRamallo It is easier to find if you learn from OpenGL ES resources and not try to copy desktop GL examples 1-by-1, as this obviously doesn't work always.